# for loop in multiselect not called first time javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, scope, multi-select

I have a multiselect dependency where I display cities and  their areas respectively. 
The problem is that, both for loops in the function getArea only get called upon the second select of the cities option element.

Note: In debugger it works fine. I think its a scope problem and I tried using the foreach function but to no avail.

I have indicated below the line where the issue occurs.

```
        //Global Variables

        var allAreas = new Array();

        $(document).ready(function() {
            getCities();
            $("#sel-city").bind("change", getAreas);

        });


        //get Cities on reload
        function getCities() {


            $.getJSON("cities.json", function(json) {

                var citySelect = $("#sel-city");

                for (var i in json) {
                    $("#sel-city")
                            .append($('<option>', {value: json[i].id})
                                    .text(json[i].name));
                }

            });
        }

        function getAreas() {

            var parentID = $(this).val();
            console.log(parentID);


            if (allAreas.length == 0) {
                $.getJSON("areas.json", function(json) {

                    for (var i in json) {
                        allAreas.push(json[i]);
                    }


                });
            }


            $('option', $("#sel-area")).remove();
            var areasByParentID = new Array();
//Loop here            
            for (var i in allAreas) {

            if (allAreas[i].city_id == parentID) {
                    areasByParentID.push(allAreas[i]);
                }
            }

            console.log(areasByParentID);

//Loop here
            for (var k in areasByParentID) {

                $("#sel-area")
                        .append($('<option>', {value: areasByParentID[k].id})
                                .text(areasByParentID[k].name));

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information you gave us and without sample data everything looks fine. But you have some minor mistakes which could lead to bad results. I decided to have a look on it, make some corrections and get it workin correctly with some sample data.

**What you should take care of?**

- use for loops instead of for-in for arrays
- you should avoid the new Array() operation
- you should cache jquery variables to reduce siteload
- for the areas to be set correctly on siteload you should just define init functions

**What here could cause an error?**

```
var a = [];
a[5] = 5;
for (var x in a) {
    // Shows only the explicitly set index of "5", and ignores 0-4
}
```

The use of the for-in statement is to enumerate over object properties and will even inherited properties. Depending on your data it could give wrong results as shown in my example.

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ws75sx0c/12/) with sample data.

Comment: I really appreciate this. Thank you very much. I only just saw the answer. 
Thanks again for the help and for the invaluable feedback.